# Growth rate of n(sin n)

Tags: functions, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Is it possible to compare the growth of functions f(n) = n and g(n) = nsin(n) in terms of O,o,Ω,ω,Θ ?

I know f(n) has linear growth, but g(n) oscillates. So is it even possible to make a comparison?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is possible as $\sin x \leq1\ \forall x \in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 0):

$|g(n)| \le |f(n)|$, so $g(n) = O(f(n))$ as $n \to \infty$.